# Hard Drive - Not Initialised

Tags: hard-drive

I have a hard drive which I need to reset.
The drive has the options -

- Limit Capacity To 32GB
- Master Or Single Drive
- Drive is slave
- Master with non-ATA-compatable slave
- Enable Cable Select
- I currently have it selected to Master.

I connect it to my laptop using a IDLE/Sata To Usb cable adapter.
When I connect it I go into my Disk Management in windows and it shows my disk as unknown and not initialised.
Don't Just say initialise it, it says Device Not Ready.
And Now It Won't Let My Press Initialise.
Any Ideas.
Sorry If this is the wrong forum.

Comment: If it shows up but you can't initialize it, my first assumption is that the drive is faulty.  When was the last time you successfully used the drive?

Comment: Does your IDE to USB adapter has an AC power plug?

Comment: Yes it does and this is plugged in and I can hear it spin up when I plug it in. I took the drive out of a pc to format it. So it was working before.